# E/RichInputConnection(1902): Batch edit level incorrect : 0

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working in a phonegap android app, but for some reason, after write some lines, the keyboard doesnt wrirte more.
In my log cat I can see:

```
05-14 13:04:04.680: E/RichInputConnection(1902): Batch edit level incorrect : 0
05-14 13:04:04.690: E/RichInputConnection(1902): com.android.inputmethod.latin.RichInputConnection.checkBatchEdit(RichInputConnection.java:80)
05-14 13:04:04.690: E/RichInputConnection(1902): com.android.inputmethod.latin.RichInputConnection.finishComposingText(RichInputConnection.java:85)
05-14 13:04:04.690: E/RichInputConnection(1902): com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.resetEntireInputState(LatinIME.java:1049)
05-14 13:04:04.690: E/RichInputConnection(1902): com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.onUpdateSelection(LatinIME.java:842)
```

I'm not sure how I can solve it.
Some one has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem, was disable the gestures in the keyboard (and in some other devices the suggestions). The android device is low gamma and the problem is releated with the memory device and not with phonegap